# What version of TFS should I install when I want to upgrade my Visual Studio 2012 to 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I work with Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 and Team Foundation Server 2012. I am planning to upgrade my VS to 2015 version.

May you please share your information with me:

1) Is it needed I upgrade my TFS version as well?

2) What is the best version of TFS for working with VS 2015?

Thanks,

Comment: Kritner, per the help center, this is a legitimate SO question (though perhaps not a good one): Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…

    a specific programming problem, or
    a software algorithm, or
    software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
    a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fery,

This page describes the compatibility between Team Foundation clients and server.  It only covers through Visual Studio 2013.  I was not able to locate a similar page for VS 2015, possibly because it is in 'Preview' as of February 2015.  However, this page indicates that VS 2013 will connect to TFS 2012 so you should be fine with VS 2015 Preview as well.

[OLD LINK] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997788.aspx

[NEW LINK] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements

More specifically to your bullet points:

1. Upgrading your Team Foundation Server is a separate question from
   upgrading Visual Studio which acts as a client for TFS.  You
   shouldn't need to change your TFS installation just because you
   updated Visual Studio.
2. I didn't find documentation regarding Visual
   Studio 2015 Preview and TFS but there is no indicator in the
   documentation for Visual Studio 2013 that you need a specific
   version to work correctly with TFS 2012.

Comment: As a moot side point, of the source control systems I have used, I found TFS to be the slowest and most cumbersome.  If you really have a choice about your source control, I'd suggest considering alternatives.

Comment: fortunately TFS also supports Git. Moving away from TFS for another source control system is apples and oranges. TFS is a complete ALM system that supports multiple version control systems

Comment: @KeithHoffman hmm you find TFS to be one of the slowest?  I've been playing around with GitHub for windows client and having a lot more issue with larger projects on GitHub than I do on TFS.  Though I do still like git repos for small stuff.  I guess you're probably not including stuff in your slow list like VSS and Vault eh? :P

Comment: The link is changed to this one. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/TFS/administer/requirements

Comment: VS2015 supports TFS2012, link provided by @JesonMartajaya